# How to Remove cache in spring mvc 3 (Back Button and refresh should not work)

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-3

My code is this :

```
<%
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
%>

    ${Sess_Var}
     <c:if test="${empty Sess_Var}" >
<%
response.sendRedirect("doLogin.obj");
%>
```

It is Not working because on clicking on back button it show the previous page.. What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide the browser (client) with the correct *headers*.
Try

```
<%        
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", "0");
%>
```

See also [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers) for cross-browsers information.

Comment: It Works Sir, Thankss, Very Much.,

Comment: Sir But It works only in Firefox.. Not in internet explorer or chrome. Sir Not able to understand why it is not working?